# Use for loop of Python to select the column index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Input:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(index=['D1','D2','D3','D4'], columns=[x for x in range(0,10)])
```

Process:

- Check the value in each row: first D2, then D2, D3, and D4
- If any values in each row >0, select the column index of this value to a list

How can I apply for loop in Python to present the procedure of 'process' step?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not fully clear.

Assuming this input:

```
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
D1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D2  NaN   -1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   -1  NaN  NaN    1  NaN    1
```

You can use:

```
out = a[a.gt(0)].apply(lambda s: s.first_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
D1    4.0
D2    2.0
D3    NaN
D4    7.0
dtype: float64
```

Or maybe you want:

```
idx, col = np.where(a.gt(0))

out = {}
for k,v in zip(a.index[idx], col):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Output:

```
{'D1': [4], 'D2': [2], 'D4': [7, 9]}
```